# Determining the angle for rotation matrix from axis and angle

Tags: graphics, 3d, linear-algebra

I have been working on 3D rotations using a 4x4 matrix. I have come across a lot of great information, but I'm lacking understanding in one topic. I have yet to understand how to determine the angle for axis.

If we look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) we'll find a wiki page describing Rotation matrix from axis and angle. I know that the axis is the cross product of the two vectors. For example:

```
Vector1: (1,0,0)
Vector2: (0,0,1)

axis = Cross(Vector1, Vector2)
```

However, I do not know how to get the angle. If anyone has any pro tips on calculating the angle I would be grateful.

Comment: this [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) might interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well-known identity linking the cross-product of two vectors to the angle between them:

[image]

Where `theta` is the *smaller* angle. However, this can be in the range `[0, 180]`, over which the inverse sine function is *multi-valued*: an acute angle `theta` is such that `sin(theta) = sin(180 - theta)`, so we can't directly obtain it from this formula.

We can use the *dot-product* instead:

[image]

The inverse cosine function *is* single-valued over this range, so we can use it!

```
dot = Dot(Vector1, Vector2)
cos = dot / (Len(Vector1) * Len(Vector2))
theta_radians = acos(cos)
theta_degrees = theta_radians * 180 / PI
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another post you might be able to help with. If you get the time you can check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986652/matrix-rotation-around-an-arbitrary-axis-bug